# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException

Tags: java, hibernate, openjpa, argumentexception

I m using Hibernate and EJB... I got EntityManager from Container, When i try to persist, I m hitting with below error.. Could some one help?

[1/25/14 23:12:46:832 CST] 00000056 SystemOut     O 2014-01-25 23:12:46 ERROR XXXXXXXService:114 - XXXXX Screening Failed
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to cast instance "XXXXXXXXVO@9941827f" to PersistenceCapable failed.  Ensure that it has been enhanced.
FailedObject: com.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.vo.XXXXXVO@9941827f
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertPersistenceCapable(BrokerImpl.java:4665)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2626)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2571)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2554)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2458)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1077)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAExEmInvocation.persist(JPAExEmInvocation.java:317)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:143)
    at XXXXXXX.persistCCCCResult(XXXXXXX.java:192)
    at XXXXXXX.prepareCCCCResponse(XXXXXXX.java:176)
    at XXXXXXX.requestCCCCCcreening(XXXXXXX.java:108)
    at XXXXXXXService.requestCCCCCcreening(CCCCCervice.java:59)
    at XXXXXXXXX,EJSRemote0SLCCCCCervice_0e27d761.requestCCCCCcreening(EJSRemote0SLCCCCCervice_0e27d761.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil$4.run(ProxyUtil.java:609)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil.invokeWithClassLoaders(ProxyUtil.java:606)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1177)
    at $Proxy225.requestCCCCCcreening(Unknown Source)
    at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.service.remote.XXXXX._CCCCCerviceRemote_Stub.requestCCCCCcreening(_CCCCCerviceRemote_Stub.java:1)
    at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.servlet.CCCCCcreening.doGet(CCCCCcreening.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
 <persistence-unit name="poc" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
   <class>XXXXXXXXX.TempVO</class>   
    <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXXX" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="XXXXX" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="XXXXX" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties> 
  </persistence-unit>

 </persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java stacktrace you are working with OpenJPA and not with Hibernate, right?

If you have enabled runtime enhancement, you must list all your entities. Did you try to enhance your Java classes using the OpenJPA enhancer? Find more information about enhancing your entities [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html).

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks.. I m using Hibernate and I didn't include OpenJAP Enhancer in My Persistance XML.

Comment: But why are there org.apache.openjpa in the stacktrace? I guess that OpenJPA is the default JPA Provider of your JEE container and that the configuration has to be fixed.